# Query to find result based on group by

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query as follows the problem is in the result I want it to be grouped by TESTTool and Release version for that particular week. So If I enter a range of dates then I should get the testtool,Releaseversion,Week No,TotalNoscripts,Pass and fail percentages for that week based on the release version and Testtool.But if I provide a range of dates it groups by dates which I do not want.

```
select TestTool,ReleaseVersion,WeekNo=DATEPART(wk,StartDate),YearNo=DATEPART(year,StartDate),
totalnoofscripts=count(ScriptName),PassPercentage=round(avg(case when Status='Pass' then 100.0 else 0.0 end), 2),
 FailPercentage=round(avg(case when Status='Fail' then 100.0 else 0.0 end), 2) 
 from CitraTestLogging.dbo.TestScript as s1,CitraTestLogging.dbo.TestRun as s2 
 where  s1.TestRun_ID=s2.ID and StartDate between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-08'
 group by TestTool,ReleaseVersion,StartDate order by TestTool,ReleaseVersion,StartDate;
```

[QueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dsGv.png)
[TableStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg6FJ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove startdate from the group by.

I added the year and week to the order by so that you get the results ordered.
Any formatted your SQL!

```
SELECT TestTool
    ,ReleaseVersion
    ,WeekNo = DATEPART(wk, StartDate)
    ,YearNo = DATEPART(year, StartDate)
    ,totalnoofscripts = count(ScriptName)
    ,PassPercentage = round(avg(CASE 
                WHEN STATUS = 'Pass'
                    THEN 100.0
                ELSE 0.0
                END), 2)
    ,FailPercentage = round(avg(CASE 
                WHEN STATUS = 'Fail'
                    THEN 100.0
                ELSE 0.0
                END), 2)
FROM CitraTestLogging.dbo.TestScript AS s1
    ,CitraTestLogging.dbo.TestRun AS s2
WHERE s1.TestRun_ID = s2.ID
    AND StartDate BETWEEN '2017-12-01'
        AND '2017-12-08'
GROUP BY TestTool
    ,ReleaseVersion
    ,DATEPART(year, StartDate)
    ,DATEPART(wk, StartDate)
ORDER BY TestTool
    ,ReleaseVersion
    ,DATEPART(year, StartDate)
    ,DATEPART(wk, StartDate);
```

Comment: If Startdate is not used in the groupBy I get the following error.Column 'CitraTestLogging.dbo.TestRun.StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MadhusmitaMohanty - Can you try the updated query please? I have replaced the WeekNo and YearNo with the functions.

Comment: Yes it works now now I get the aggregate the way I wanted.Thanks !